# Getting Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm implementing a link in React and TypesSript that, after clicking, scrolls to the right component, I'm using useRef Hook.

But when I do that, the error occurs:

```
Type '{ ref: MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
```

Below  is the code, what am I doing wrong? I've tried several ways.

```
  import NewComponent from '../NewComponent';

  const titleRef = useRef<null | HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const handleBackClick = (): any => {
    titleRef!.current!.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  };

return (
  <Container>
    <Link onClick={handleBackClick}>
      Button Text
    </Link>
     ...
     ...
     ...
     <SomeComponents />
     ...
     ...
     ...
     ...

   <NewComponent ref={titleRef} />
  </Container>
)
```

The `NewComponent` is a simple component, like:

```
const NewComponent = () => {
  
    return (
      <Container>
        // Its a simple component
      </Container>
    );
  };
  
  export default NewComponent;
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me with this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would wanna use [`forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref) to tell TypeScript that `NewComponent` can accept a `ref` that will hold a `div` element. Here is how you would do it as an example:

```
import { forwardRef, ReactNode } from "react";

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const NewComponent = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, Props>((props, ref) => {
  return <div ref={ref}>{props.children}</div>;
});

export default NewComponent;
```

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import NewComponent from "./NewComponent";

export default function App() {
  const titleRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  return <NewComponent ref={titleRef}>Some content</NewComponent>;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In React, `ref` can only attach to DOM, if you want to pass it to your react component, you should use `forwardRef`

you can find more detail here
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand very well how to use forwardRef using the example above, can you give me an example? Thanks